# "Exclude these words" feature

Tags: lucene

How do I implement "Exclude these words" feature for a search appliation using Lucene?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean stop words?  What version of Lucene?

Answer (score 1):

therefor i can use the stopanalyzer:

StopAnalyzer    StopAnalyzer includes the lower-case filter, and also has a filter that drops out any "stop words", words like articles (a, an, the, etc) that occur so commonly in english that they might as well be noise for searching purposes. StopAnalyzer comes with a set of stop words, but you can instantiate it with your own array of stop words.

http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_0/api/org/apache/lucene/analysis/StopAnalyzer.html

more information:
http://www.darksleep.com/lucene/
[How to sort by Lucene.Net field and ignore common stop words such as 'a' and 'the'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66041/how-to-sort-by-lucene-net-field-and-ignore-common-stop-words-such-as-a-and-the)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the NOT operator [here](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/queryparsersyntax.html).  Just construct your query accordingly or massage if it is a user-generated query.